# How can I programmatically change the Windows 11 color scheme?

Tags: windows, powershell, colors

For reference, here's what I'm trying to change:
[image: Image of part of Settings, containing color options]

Is there a way to programmatically change this (preferably via PowerShell)?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SuperUser, TheTank20.

The Accent Color settings are stored in the registry under the following key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent`

There are some DWORD values that can be modified to change the Accent Color. The value is stored as hexadecimal, in RGB format, with a `00` at the end. Don't remove the `00`. Replace RRGGBB with your preferred color.

`0xRRGGBB00`

You might want to check out [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/sw15u0/dark_theme_did_you_notice_the_ugly_pale_accent/) where there was a discussion on apps and scripts that modify these settings.

Once you have everything figured out, you can script the registry changes.

Here is an **untested** code sample that may produce the desired outputs:

```
# Define the new accent color (e.g., #FF0000 for red)
$NewAccentColor = "#FF0000"

# Convert the hex color code to an integer for the registry value
$ColorValue = [System.Convert]::ToInt32($NewAccentColor -replace "#", "", [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::HexNumber)

# Set the AccentColor and AccentColorMenu registry values
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" -Name "AccentColor" -Value $ColorValue -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" -Name "AccentColorMenu" -Value $ColorValue -Type DWord

# Log off and back on or restart the Windows Explorer to see the changes take effect
```

Comment: For some reason, I had to change the 5th line in the code block, because of a Powershell error on Windows 11 (**Cannot find an overload for "ToInt32" and the argument count: "3".**) to:

`$ColorValue = [System.Convert]::ToInt32($NewAccentColor.Replace("#", ""), 16)`